# Project Reactor - Finding if processing of all the child nodes are completed using DFS

Tags: java, spring-boot, recursion, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am new to the reactive world!

I have the below tree structure and am doing a DFS on the tree, i want to find out when the processing of child nodes are completed for each of the parent nodes.

```
A -- AA -- AAA
  |     -- AAB
  |     -- AAC
  -- AB
  -- AC
  -- AD
  -- AE -- AEA
        -- AEB
```

While doing the DFS (expandDeep) on a tree, the doOnComplete on the parent is getting emitted before completion of childnodes.

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Singular;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Config config = getConfig();
        Mono.just(config)
                .expandDeep(c -> Flux.fromIterable(c.getChildren()).doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("Complete: " + c.getName())))
                .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("Processing complete... !!"))
                .map(s -> s.getName())
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Config getConfig() {

        Config config = Config.builder().name("A")
                .child(Config.builder().name("AA")
                        .child(Config.builder().name("AAA").build())
                        .child(Config.builder().name("AAB").build())
                        .child(Config.builder().name("AAC").build())
                        .build())
                .child(Config.builder().name("AB").build())
                .child(Config.builder().name("AC").build())
                .child(Config.builder().name("AD").build())
                .child(Config.builder().name("AE")
                        .child(Config.builder().name("AEA").build())
                        .child(Config.builder().name("AEB").build())
                        .build())
                .build();
        return config;
    }

    @Builder
    @Data
    private static final class Config {

        private String name;

        @Singular("child")
        private List<Config> children;

    }

}
```

Below is the output of the program

```
A
AA
AAA
Complete: AAA
AAB
Complete: AAB
Complete: AA
AAC
Complete: AAC
AB
Complete: AB
AC
Complete: AC
AD
Complete: AD
Complete: A
AE
AEA
Complete: AEA
Complete: AE
AEB
Complete: AEB
Processing complete... !!
```

Expected Result

```
A
AA
AAA
Complete: AAA
AAB
Complete: AAB
AAC
Complete: AAC
Complete: AA
AB
Complete: AB
AC
Complete: AC
AD
Complete: AD
AE
AEA
Complete: AEA
AEB
Complete: AEB
Complete: AE
Complete: A
Processing complete... !!
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because each of the child processing are actually separate `Flux`, to which you attach the `doOnComplete`. So as soon as one parent has spitted out its last child, even though the child hasn't yet been recursively processed, the parent is considered completed.

`doAfterTerminate` *might* help (it is executed after the completion signal has been propagated downstream).

Comment: Even i tried using `doAfterTerminate`, it is the same order being called.